# Android simultaneously use Pull to Refresh ListView at the top and automatically Load more data when scroll to the Bottom

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

Please read it carefully before marking it as **duplicate**. I am using pulltorefresh
from [this library](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) and I am implimenting pulltorefresh on the top of screen using following code:

```
listView.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_START);
```

Now i also want to use ListView automatically Load more data when scroll to the Bottom of the screen. Is it possible with using pulltorefresh library? If not please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

set `OnScrollListener` listener to your `ListView`. Based on number of items displayed, get new rows from web(Asynchronously) and add them to ArrayList(or whatever you are using to populate your list) and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.